# Interrupted update OS

Tags: software-installation, updates, interrupts

I decided to update OS to 14.04. While downloading packages i noticed download totally stopped and had to interrupt it, and that happened several times. Then it started installing everything and it froze again. I waited for few h and it didnt changed anything. So i restarted pc and problem happened(knew that i shouldn't do it). Now when login to my account, after 1 second it just logs out.Only thing that i can do is login as guest user, but as a guest i can't use sudo in terminal.Guys, please tell me what should i do,i'm not so fammiliar with linux and i need to change os to windows.Do i need to reinstall linux first and how ?I need help asap,thanks.

Comment: What version were you upgrading from? Things often go wrong when upgrading like that, it is better to do a [fresh install](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328/364819), and I think that you should at least try that before trying to get Windows back on, but if you really want to get Windows back and you have some sort of live media with it installed on, then you can follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Switch on` your computer.

`Press` and `hold` the `Shift key`, which will bring up the `Grub menu`.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `(recovery mode)`

Press `Return` and your computer will begin the boot process.

Your computer should display a menu with a number of options.

One of the options will be `Check all file systems`.

Press `Return` with this option `highlighted.`

Other of the options will be `Enable networking`.

Press `Return` with this option `highlighted.`

Other of the options will be `Drop to root shell prompt`.

Press `Return` with this option `highlighted.`

Your computer should boot in a terminal, so enter the commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get autoremove
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: In grub menu i have next:-ubuntu with linux 3. 13.0-65-generic and 3. 13.0-65-generic(safe mode).No recovery option.What should i do now.Thanks for reply.